# Symfony 2 : HWiOauthBundle : Overriding connect_success.html.twig

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I have implemented both FOSUserBundle and HWIOauthBundle in my Symfony 2 project. Basically, everything works fine but I would like to customize a litle bit more. Typically I use the *connect* functionnality of the HWIOauthBundle to connect oauth account to user already connected with the authentication form (FOSUserBundle).

In case of succes, the controller action *HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connectService* displays the twig template *connect_success.html.twig*. At this point, I would like to override this template and do the following actions :

1. Create a flash message
2. Display the flash message on my homepage

You can obtain this behavior easily with FOSUserBundle as this bundle dispatchs many events to hook into the controllers. But with HWIOauthBundle this is not possible.

My solution is the following :

1/ I override *connect_success.html.twig* by placing the same named file in *app/Ressources/HWIOauthBundle/views/Connect* with the following code:

```
{{ render(controller('MyUserBundle:User:HWIOAuthFlash')) }}
```

2/ In my user controller (*MyUserBundle:User*), I create an action *HWIOAuthFlashAction()* that defines a flash message and forwards to the controller action that displays he homepage(*MyMainBundle:Main:homepage*)

```
    public function HWIOAuthFlashAction()
    {
    // Here : flash message definition

    return $this->forward('MyMainBundle:Main:homepage');
   }
```

At this point the homepage is displayed with the flash message. But I had to remove two links in the homepage template (*homepage.twig.html*)that permits the user to switch between two locales.

The following code is the one that I had to remove from my template :

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ path( app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get( '_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'} )) }}">FR</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path( app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get( '_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'} )) }}">EN</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I understand that that the special variable *_route* is null. And I get the following message :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Error when rendering
>   "xxxxx/web/app_dev.php/connect/service/google?key=yyyyyyy" (Status
>   code is 500).") in HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect_success.html.twig at
>   line 3.

I have two questions :

1. To achieve my goal, is it the good way ?
2. How to say to symfony that I want my route to be *homepage* ?

Comment: I think I can test if *_route* is null. In this case I force the route to be *homepage*. To be tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed in my comment, here is my solution :

In my homepage template *homepage.twig.html* :

```
{% set route = app.request.get('_route') ? app.request.get('_route') : 'homepage' %}

      <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ path(route, app.request.get( '_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'fr'} )) }}">FR</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ path(route, app.request.get( '_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'} )) }}">EN</a></li>
      </ul>
```